# how can we sort the list items in drop down list in asp.net programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list,
that dropdownlist binded programatically with database,
when my page loads my dropdown list items should display in sorting order,
so, here how can I sort the dropdown list items....?
please provide code,

thank you...,

Comment: Sort the data before binding it to the dropdownlist.

Comment: Are you bind dropdown using dataset ?

Comment: Sort them in the sql query.

Comment: Order them before you bind them, preferably an the database level or am I missing something?

Comment: @Utkarsh  yes, I'm binding dropdown using dataset only,

Comment: see the answer now i have made some changes according to your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take a DataTable to put the data of The Dataset

```
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

and then 
you can create a DataView of your Datatable and then bind the drop down list to that. Your code will be like this then

```
DataView dvlist = new DataView(table);
dvlist.Sort = "Description";

ddllist.DataSource = dvlist;
ddllist.DataTextField = "Description";
ddllist.DataValueField = "Id";
ddllist.DataBind();
```

hope you find your solution now

Comment: thankyou, could you tell me what is DataTableWithList in above code...?

Comment: DataTableWithList is the DataTable which you get from Database

Comment: you might have written some query to return a data table,correct?